# Calculate amount of days worked by employee from 1 column to another with a function

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my function I have so long, I need to be able to just call it with with an Employee number from the Employee table and it has to calculate the days between the 2 columns.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getDaysWorked (@Employee_No int)
Returns Datetime  
as  
Begin   
declare @DayStart datetime  
declare @DayResigned datetime
declare @DaysWorked int
  
set @DayStart =   (Select e.Group_Start_Date) from Employee e
set @DayResigned =(Select e.ResignDate) from Employee e
set @DaysWorked = (@DayStart - @DayResigned) 
Return(@DaysWorked)  
end  
GO
```

If there is a better way please let me know, this is what I have...

Comment: I would, personally, suggest using an **inline** table value function, not a multi-line scalar function. The former are significantly more performant.

Comment: Your current logic does not count days **worked**. Most people do not "work" on holidays, vacation days, weekends, etc. Be specific about your goal. In addition, you can put this calculation into a computed column for that table and NEVER need to compute the value directly.

Comment: And a note about datatypes. Surely you do not store a time value for either date so using datetime datatype is only asking for accidental errors to creep into your system. And don't use mathematical operators with date (or related) values - use datediff as already suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want something related to the employee being passed in.  I would surmise:

```
create function getDaysWorked (@Employee_No int)
returns int as  
begin   
    declare @DaysWorked int;
  
    select @DaysWorked = datediff(day, e.Group_Start_Date, e.ResignDate)
    from Employee e
    where e.Employee_No = @Employee_No;

    return(@DaysWorked)  
end;
```

Note that the function returns an integer not a date.

Comment: Just needed a ) bracket begin e.ResignDate but it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getDaysWorked (@Employee_No int)
Returns int
as  
Begin   
declare @DaysWorked int

SELECT @DaysWorked = DATEDIFF(day,e.Group_Start_Date,e.ResignDate) FROM from Employee e WHERE Emp_ID=@Employee_No 
Return(@DaysWorked)  
end  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Datediff is the function you want to use indeed. However this has a little caveat emptor which needs to be handled by business logic.

Does the first day of employment counts towards the days worked or is this considered day = 0 and thus not counted?

Concept code (without function):

```
WITH
  cte_employee
(
  code_employee,
  dtt_start,
  dtt_resigned
)
AS
( -- result expected as a lot of days
  SELECT 
    Cast( 1 AS smallint ) AS code_employee,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '1988-01-01', 126 ) AS dtt_start,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '1995-03-06', 126 ) AS dtt_resigned
  UNION
  -- no result possible
  SELECT 
    Cast( 2 AS smallint ) AS code_employee,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '2000-01-01', 126 ) AS dtt_start,
    Convert( datetime2(0), NULL, 126 ) AS dtt_resigned
  UNION
  -- result expected as 365 day (no leap year)
  SELECT 
    Cast( 3 AS smallint ) AS code_employee,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '2005-04-01', 126 ) AS dtt_start,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '2006-03-31', 126 ) AS dtt_resigned
  UNION
  -- result expected as 366 day (no leap year)
  SELECT 
    Cast( 4 AS smallint ) AS code_employee,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '1999-04-01', 126 ) AS dtt_start,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '2000-03-31', 126 ) AS dtt_resigned
)
SELECT
  code_employee,
  dtt_start,
  dtt_resigned,
  -- first day is considered day 0 so add 1
  Datediff( dd, dtt_start, dtt_resigned ) +1 AS days_worked
FROM
  cte_employee
;
```

Now the SQL function is out of the way let us check two options to create a function itself. For this I use scalar (UDF = user defined function) and ITVF (inline table valued function).

The ITVF is very primitive and just demonstrates the concept for OUTER APPLY.

> Please do not under any circumstances use the following code in your production environment!

First there must be a table to work with:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TestEmployee
;
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestEmployee
(
  code_employee    smallint,
  dtt_start        datetime2(0),
  dtt_resigned     datetime2(0)
)
;
WITH
  cte_employee
(
  code_employee,
  dtt_start,
  dtt_resigned
)
AS
( -- result expected as a lot of days
  SELECT 
    Cast( 1 AS smallint ) AS code_employee,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '1988-01-01', 126 ) AS dtt_start,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '1995-03-06', 126 ) AS dtt_resigned
  UNION
  -- no result possible
  SELECT 
    Cast( 2 AS smallint ) AS code_employee,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '2000-01-01', 126 ) AS dtt_start,
    Convert( datetime2(0), NULL, 126 ) AS dtt_resigned
  UNION
  -- result expected as 365 day (no leap year)
  SELECT 
    Cast( 3 AS smallint ) AS code_employee,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '2005-04-01', 126 ) AS dtt_start,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '2006-03-31', 126 ) AS dtt_resigned
  UNION
  -- result expected as 366 day (no leap year)
  SELECT 
    Cast( 4 AS smallint ) AS code_employee,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '1999-04-01', 126 ) AS dtt_start,
    Convert( datetime2(0), '2000-03-31', 126 ) AS dtt_resigned
)
INSERT INTO dbo.TestEmployee
(
  code_employee,
  dtt_start,
  dtt_resigned
)
SELECT
  code_employee,
  dtt_start,
  dtt_resigned
FROM
  cte_employee
;
GO
```

And with a few records to work with here comes the scalar function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION udf_count_days_worked
( -- what is required?
  @code_employee    smallint
)
-- what is delivered?
RETURNS int
WITH
  SCHEMABINDING,              -- important if this function shall continue to work
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT  -- just a fail safe
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    @num_days_worked    int
  ;
  SELECT
    @num_days_worked = Datediff( dd, dtt_start, dtt_resigned ) +1
  FROM
    dbo.TestEmployee
  WHERE
      code_employee = @code_employee
  ;
  RETURN
    @num_days_worked
  ;
END
;

GO

SELECT
  emp.code_employee,
  emp.dtt_start,
  emp.dtt_resigned,
  dbo.udf_count_days_worked( emp.code_employee ) AS num_days_worked
FROM
  dbo.TestEmployee AS emp
;
```

In a scalar function I use the function itself PER ROW using a variable derived from the table.

On to ITVF. The main benefit over a scalar function is the single execution instead of row-by-agonizing-row execution of a scalar function.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION itvf_count_days_worked
(
  @code_employee   smallint
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH 
  SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT
    --code_employee, 
    Datediff( dd, dtt_start, dtt_resigned ) +1 AS num_days_worked
  FROM
    dbo.TestEmployee
  WHERE
      code_employee = @code_employee
)
;

GO

SELECT
  emp.code_employee,
  emp.dtt_start,
  emp.dtt_resigned,
  func.num_days_worked
FROM
  dbo.TestEmployee AS emp
  OUTER APPLY dbo.itvf_count_days_worked( emp.code_employee ) AS func
;
```

As mentioned this ITVF is primitive. The main benefit is speed as long as the return values are simple calculations. Now these calculations can be lots of code to find the correct result. Using either scalar or ITVF allows to "hide" the code in a function and thus apply the same calculation at different places.

And finally some clean up code:

```
-- clean up
DROP FUNCTION udf_count_days_worked
;
DROP FUNCTION itvf_count_days_worked
;
DROP TABLE dbo.TestEmployee
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in comment, I would use an inline table-value function. It seems odd, however, that you return a `datetime`, but if that's what you want, at least make it more clear you want this odd logic in your SQL by explicitly using `DATEADD` to add the difference in days to the "date" `0` (`1900-01-01`):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getDaysWorked (@Employee_No int)
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEDIFF(DAY,e.Group_Start_Date,e.ResignDate)) AS DaysWorked
    FROM dbo.Employee;
    --WHERE EmployeeNo = @Employee_No --This wasn't in your attempt either, oddly.
GO
```

So, if someone joined on `2017-01-01` and left on `2021-02-10'` it would return the `datetime` value `1904-02-02T00:00:00.000`.

Comment: Explain how to use it with `CROSS APPLY`